# Writing for child birth certificate

Tags: grammar

Is it correct when you say, "I and my wife had our second baby last month" ?.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I put myself last? "me and my friends" vs. "my friends and me" or "my friends and I"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/should-i-put-myself-last-me-and-my-friends-vs-my-friends-and-me-or-my-fri) OR ['I and my wife' or 'my wife and I'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/291902/i-and-my-wife-or-my-wife-and-i)

Comment: Thank you, yes, "my wife and I had our second baby last month" sounds great :)